# Multiple foreign keys for one relation in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have two django models like this:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    ...
    grade_value_order = models.ForeignKey('GradeValues', db_column="WART_OC_KOLEJNOSC",  related_name="REC_WART_OC_FK")
    grade_type = models.ForeignKey('GradeValues', db_column="TOC_KOD", related_name="REC_WART_OC_FK")

    class Meta:
        ...
        managed = False

class GradeValues(models.Model):
    grade_order = models.IntegerField(db_column="KOLEJNOSC", primary_key=True)
    grade_type = models.ForeignKey('GradeType', db_column="TOC_KOD", primary_key=True)
    ...
```

As you see, there're 2 primary keys in GradeValues class and 2 foreign keys in Review. They're supposed to constitude one to many relation between GradeValues and Reviews. But it doesn't work. How to force this? I use a read only Oracle db, so I can't modify anything.

Comment: What doesn't work? And you can't have two primary keys for one table.

Comment: When I type e.g. Review.objects.all()[1].grade_type I get raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist

Comment: And it does exist? What's in `TOC_KOD` column of desired review row? And what's primary key of `GradeValues` table? Is it multicolumn?

Comment: OK, it seems that we've got a problem with db. But yeah, primary key is multicolumn. I apologise for bother.

Comment: Django [does not support](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) multicolumn pks.

Comment: Houston, we've got a problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do what you are describing, but I don't think you have to change the underlying database at all.

You need to create a many-to-many relationship explicitly between GradeValues and itself[1] and specify Review as the intermediate table[2]

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical

[2] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Somewhere in those documentation pages and some playing around I think you might find your answer.